# Visual Studio 2017 studio showing error 'This application is in break mode' and throws unhandled exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing a Xamarin.Android app. Whenever i try to download a JSON feed I get the error **"Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code"**.

Here's the screenshot of error
[image: Here's the screenshot of error]

- My json feed download code

  ```
   string url = "http://xamdev.epizy.com/getData1.php";

   public async void downloadJsonFeedAsync(String url) {
      var httpClient = new HttpClient();
      Task<string> contentsTask = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

      // await! control returns to the caller and the task continues to run on another thread
      string content = await contentsTask;
      Console.Out.WriteLine("Response Body: \r\n {0}", content);

      //Convert string to JSON object
      result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject> (content);

      //Update listview
      RunOnUiThread (() => {
          listView.Adapter = new CusotmListAdapter(this, result.posts);
          progress.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
      });
  }
  ```
- i have got error at this line

  string content = await contentsTask;
- This is my json

  {
     "posts":[
        {
           "id":"1",
           "url":"",
           "title":"Convert Speech to Text in Android Application",
           "date":"2017-06-16 06:15:18",
           "content":"Convert Speech to Tex Convert Speech to Text in Android Application Convert Speech to Text in Android Applicationt in Android Application",
           "thumbnail":"http:\/\/stacktips.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/01\/Speech-to-Text-in-Android-375x300.jpeg"
        }
     ]
  }

Please can anybody tell me whats wrong with my code ?
Thanks in advance..

**Here's my php webservice code**-

```
<?php 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

    require_once('conn.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM space";


    if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
     {
      $resultArray = array();
      $tempArray = array();


       while($row = $result->fetch_object())
       {

         $tempArray = $row;
          array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
      }


    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$resultArray));
    }
        mysqli_close($conn);

     }
   ?>
```

Comment: you have an unhandled exception.  Either use the debugger to view the exception details, or try putting a try/catch around your code to catch it

Comment: There's no easy way to tell.  You'd be best to add a logging mechanism to your code that can output exceptions from the various threads.

Comment: @Jason , I've tried using try catch blocks. Its just showing break-mode screen. Nothing specific error.

Comment: I tested the URL, and I can get the response without any problem. But the response is not a json object but an html.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Can you help me with correcting code of php webservices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i got the answer.

Problem was with my hosting server, server response with cookies in it. That's why my android app unable to parse the json.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 14):

I'm surprised yet not best answer posted for this issue. For me above solutions didn't work. To resolve this issue, I'd to disable following option from debug menu.

```
Debug > Options > General > Uncheck "Enable Just My Code"
```

For more details, check [microsoft msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx) help.

Comment: Did this but I still get the error. So this step didnt work for me.

Answer (score 3):

You should be getting exception details and a call stack, which will greatly aid in your debugging efforts.  I think this is a bug with Xamarin on VS2017 right now.

Comment: Thank you. I checked the console and saw that vs failing to load a library. I removed the line of code which require that library and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this error and looked in the output window after the application failed.  In my case I had a method in a view model class with a "Task" that is invoked by the XMAL.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case I checked the debug output window and it mentioned "Cannot find or open the PDB file." I further read and one of the solutions was to check what static variable references I was making. I had a static variable loading from the AppSettings and it was referencing a key that was not present in the app.Config file. I wish the debugger told me directly the reference not found or something like that. Once I had the correct reference key, I was on my way. Hoping this will help somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone:

The output tab was giving me a message saying that the dll version was incorrect.

The project ran anyway, but for some reason this dll version made my project to go to break mode, I deleted the dll, used a previous version, and now I can debug without problems